# How to get javax.validation payload validation for spring-cloud-aws in QueueMessageHandler working?

Tags: spring-cloud, spring-cloud-aws

I'm writing some message consumer for an AWS SQS and want to validate the received message by using the javax.validation.constraints annotations.
Unfortunately I had to find out, that the used PayloadArgumentResolver of the spring-cloud-aws-messaging dependency uses a NoOpValidator.
So I tried to inject my own HandlerMethodArgumentResolver for the payload.

```
  @Bean
  public QueueMessageHandlerFactory queueMessageHandlerFactory(
      final ObjectMapper objectMapper, final Validator hibernateValidator) {
    final MappingJackson2MessageConverter jacksonMessageConverter =
        new MappingJackson2MessageConverter();
    jacksonMessageConverter.setSerializedPayloadClass(String.class);
    jacksonMessageConverter.setStrictContentTypeMatch(true);
    jacksonMessageConverter.setObjectMapper(objectMapper);
    final QueueMessageHandlerFactory factory = new QueueMessageHandlerFactory();

    final List<HandlerMethodArgumentResolver> argumentResolvers = new ArrayList<>();
    argumentResolvers.add(new HeaderMethodArgumentResolver(null, null));
    argumentResolvers.add(new HeadersMethodArgumentResolver());

    argumentResolvers.add(new NotificationSubjectArgumentResolver());
    argumentResolvers.add(new AcknowledgmentHandlerMethodArgumentResolver("Acknowledgment"));
    argumentResolvers.add(new VisibilityHandlerMethodArgumentResolver("Visibility"));

    final PayloadArgumentResolver payloadArgumentResolver =
        new PayloadArgumentResolver(jacksonMessageConverter, hibernateValidator);
    argumentResolvers.add(payloadArgumentResolver);

    factory.setArgumentResolvers(argumentResolvers);
    return factory;
  }
```

So far so good and at first sight, it works well...
BUT as you can see I had to add the already in QueueMessageHandler existing argument resolvers as well to resolve the headers via @Headers/@Header of the message, too.

```
  @SqsListener(
      value = "queue",
      deletionPolicy = SqsMessageDeletionPolicy.ON_SUCCESS)
  public void consume(
      @Payload @Validated final QueueMessage queueMessage,
      @Headers final Map<String,Object> headers) {
  }
```

When I only add my PayloadArgumentResolver with the hibernate validator, it will be also used to resolve the headers, doh!

Is there any pretty solution for this or should I open an issue at spring-cloud-aws? I just want my payload to be validated via annotations :(

Comment: i open a ticket on git https://github.com/awspring/spring-cloud-aws/discussions/532

Answer (score -1):

I don't think this is the best awswer but I have a working sample project that have this type of validation: https://github.com/Haple/sqslistener

```
@Data
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
@NoArgsConstructor(access = AccessLevel.PRIVATE, force = true)
public class EventDTO {

  @NotNull(message = "foo is mandatory")
  private final String foo;

  @NotNull(message = "bar is mandatory")
  private final String bar;

}
```

```
@Slf4j
@Service
@AllArgsConstructor
public class SampleListener {

  @SqsListener("test_queue")
  public void execute(final @Valid @Payload EventDTO event) {
    log.info("OK: {}", event);
  }

}
```

```
@Configuration
public class MessageHandler {
  @Bean
  QueueMessageHandler queueMessageHandler(final AmazonSQSAsync amazonSQSAsync,
      final MessageConverter messageConverter,
      final Validator validator) {
    final QueueMessageHandlerFactory queueMessageHandlerFactory = new QueueMessageHandlerFactory();
    final PayloadMethodArgumentResolver payloadMethodArgumentResolver = new PayloadMethodArgumentResolver(messageConverter, validator);
    queueMessageHandlerFactory.setArgumentResolvers(Collections.singletonList(payloadMethodArgumentResolver));
    queueMessageHandlerFactory.setAmazonSqs(amazonSQSAsync);
    queueMessageHandlerFactory.setMessageConverters(Collections.singletonList(messageConverter));
    return queueMessageHandlerFactory.createQueueMessageHandler();
  }
}
```

Comment: Please [edit] your answer to:
improve code formatting
,
 include an explaination of how this works and why it is solution of the problem?
See [answer]